# Axios does not send HTTP post request

Tags: node.js, httprequest, axios, alexa-skills-kit

I have trouble doing a http post request within my alexa skill in nodejs with axios

I have used axios prior to this project and never had any trouble sending CRUD request.

My request handler looks like this:

```
const handlers = {

    'LaunchRequest': function () {
      this.emit(':ask', 'What is your emergency?', 'How can I help you' )
    },
    'InjuryHelpIntent': function () {
      const accessToken = this.event.context.System.user.accessToken
      const userId= this.event.context.System.user.userId
      console.log('user id: ', userId)
      getDeviceAddress(this.event)
      .then((address) => {
          const res = sendHelp(address,accessToken)
          console.log(res)
          this.emit(':tell', 'Succes!')
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error message: ',error)
        this.emit(':tell', error)
      })


    },

}
```

Within the `sendHelp(address, token)` function I make the call to a REST Service.

SendHelp.js:

```
const axios = require('axios')
module.exports = (address, token) => {
    axios.post('https://api-sandbox.safetrek.io/v1/alarms')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      return response})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      return error})

}
```

In the meanwhile i had tried to post data but nothing worked not even an unauthorized call like my desperate attempt you see in `sendHelp.js` here.
I expect t get a 401 error because of missing authorization. `const res` in my handler should be a json object but instead I get `undefined`. It completely skips the POST request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a value from an async function like `axios.post()` and expect to simply receive the returned value synchronously. In other words, this isn't going to work:

```
const res = sendHelp(address,accessToken)
```

for two reasons. First `sendHelp()` isn't actually returning anything. And even if it did it would need to return a promise, not the result of the async axios function. You need to return the promise from axios and then call `then()` on it. For example:

```
const axios = require('axios')
module.exports = (address, token) => {
    // axios.post() returns a promise. Return that promise to the caller
    return axios.post('https://api-sandbox.safetrek.io/v1/alarms')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        return error
    })
}
```

Now you can use that promise with something like:

```
getDeviceAddress(this.event)
 .then((address) => sendHelp(address,accessToken))
 .then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    this.emit(':tell', 'Succes!')
  })
 .catch(err => handleError())
```

Comment: Thank you very much that was it, literally just needed to return axios.post!